# How can i remove the vaadin test licence?

Tags: frontend, vaadin

I had some weeks ago a trial for the Vaadin Board (Chart). After the trial i removed the dependency in pom. But since then i receive this error message wgen building the frontend:
The provided license key does not allow usage of vaadin-board 2.2.1. Check that the license has not expired and that the product you are trying to use does not require another type of subscription.

I already removed the maven repository, ran mvn clean install and did the vaadin dance. But nothing worked. I could not build the frontend again. Does anyone has the same system?

Here is my pom.xml

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.myapp.app</groupId>
    <artifactId>myapp-admin</artifactId>
    <name>myapp-Admin</name>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>

        <!--nicht updaten VStepper sonst nicht kompatible-->
        <vaadin.version>14.10.0</vaadin.version>

    </properties>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.7</version>
    </parent>

    <repositories>
        <!-- The order of definitions matters. Explicitly defining central here to make sure it has the highest priority. -->

        <!-- Main Maven repository -->
        <repository>
            <id>central</id>
            <url>https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
        <!-- Repository used by many Vaadin add-ons -->
        <repository>
            <id>Vaadin Directory</id>
            <url>https://maven.vaadin.com/vaadin-addons</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
        <!--FTP4J-->
        <repository>
            <id>github-asbachb-releases</id>
            <url>https://raw.github.com/asbachb/mvn-repo/master/releases</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

    <pluginRepositories>
        <!-- Main Maven repository -->
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>central</id>
            <url>https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </pluginRepository>
    </pluginRepositories>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
                <artifactId>vaadin-bom</artifactId>
                <version>${vaadin.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jsoup</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsoup</artifactId>
            <version>1.15.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.mlottmann.VStepper</groupId>
            <artifactId>VStepper</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.9</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.github.appreciated</groupId>
            <artifactId>apexcharts</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.0.beta9</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.iban4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>iban4j</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.3-RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.flywaydb</groupId>
            <artifactId>flyway-core</artifactId>
            <version>6.0.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.github.oshi</groupId>
            <artifactId>oshi-core</artifactId>
            <version>5.7.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.googlecode.json-simple</groupId>
            <artifactId>json-simple</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.pdfbox</groupId>
            <artifactId>pdfbox</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.25</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency> <!--SEPA QR-->
            <groupId>net.glxn.qrgen</groupId>
            <artifactId>javase</artifactId>
            <version>2.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency><!--SEPA QR-->
            <groupId>de.deltatree.tools</groupId>
            <artifactId>qrsct</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.github.ulisesbocchio</groupId>
            <artifactId>jasypt-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>de.codecamp.vaadin</groupId>
            <artifactId>vaadin-message-dialog</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>dev.mett.vaadin</groupId>
            <artifactId>tooltip</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>xerces</groupId>
            <artifactId>xercesImpl</artifactId>
            <version>2.6.2-jaxb-1.0.6</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jasypt</groupId>
            <artifactId>jasypt-hibernate5</artifactId>
            <version>1.9.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.vaadin.olli</groupId>
            <artifactId>file-download-wrapper</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-mail</artifactId>
            <version>2.6.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.vaadin.klaudeta</groupId>
            <artifactId>grid-pagination</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.10</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>de.f0rce.signaturepad</groupId>
            <artifactId>signature-widget</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
            <!-- Replace artifactId with vaadin-core to use only free components -->
            <artifactId>vaadin</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <!-- Webjars are only needed when running in Vaadin 13 compatibility mode -->
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>com.vaadin.webjar</groupId>
                    <artifactId>*</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.webjars.bowergithub.insites</groupId>
                    <artifactId>*</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.webjars.bowergithub.polymer</groupId>
                    <artifactId>*</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.webjars.bowergithub.polymerelements</groupId>
                    <artifactId>*</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.webjars.bowergithub.vaadin</groupId>
                    <artifactId>*</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.webjars.bowergithub.webcomponents</groupId>
                    <artifactId>*</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
            <artifactId>vaadin-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <!-- Excluding so that webjars are not included. -->
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
                    <artifactId>vaadin-core</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.vaadin.artur</groupId>
            <artifactId>a-vaadin-helper</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.github.asbachb</groupId>
            <artifactId>ftp4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Bean validation implementation-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate.validator</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
            <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
            <version>31.0.1-jre</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <version>1.18.24</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
            <version>3.11</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
            <version>5.3.2</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
            <version>5.3.2</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
            <artifactId>vaadin-testbench</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.sf.jasperreports</groupId>
            <artifactId>jasperreports</artifactId>
            <version>6.19.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.github.bonigarcia</groupId>
            <artifactId>webdrivermanager</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.github.eirslett</groupId>
            <artifactId>frontend-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.12.1</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <finalName>admin</finalName>
        <defaultGoal>spring-boot:run</defaultGoal>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <!-- Clean build and startup time for Vaadin apps sometimes may exceed
                     the default Spring Boot's 30sec timeout.  -->
                <configuration>
                    <wait>500</wait>
                    <maxAttempts>240</maxAttempts>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <!--
                Take care of synchronizing java dependencies and imports in
                package.json and main.js files.
                It also creates webpack.config.js if not exists yet.
            -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
                <artifactId>vaadin-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${vaadin.version}</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>prepare-frontend</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>11</source>
                    <target>11</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <!-- Production mode is activated using -Pproduction -->
            <id>production</id>
            <properties>
                <vaadin.productionMode>true</vaadin.productionMode>
            </properties>

            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
                    <artifactId>flow-server-production-mode</artifactId>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>

            <build>
                <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>com.github.eirslett</groupId>
                        <artifactId>frontend-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                        <!-- Use the latest released version:
                        https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/github/eirslett/frontend-maven-plugin/ -->
                        <version>1.12.1</version>

                        <executions>
                            <execution>
                                <!-- optional: you don't really need execution ids, but it looks nice in your build log. -->
                                <id>install node and npm</id>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>install-node-and-npm</goal>
                                </goals>
                                <!-- optional: default phase is "generate-resources" -->
                                <phase>generate-resources</phase>
                            </execution>
                        </executions>
                        <configuration>
                            <nodeVersion>v16.14.2</nodeVersion>

                            <!-- optional: with node version greater than 4.0.0 will use npm provided by node distribution -->
                            <!--                    <npmVersion>2.15.9</npmVersion>-->

                            <!-- optional: where to download node and npm from. Defaults to https://nodejs.org/dist/ -->
                            <!--                    <downloadRoot>http://myproxy.example.org/nodejs/</downloadRoot>-->
                        </configuration>
                    </plugin>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                        <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                        <configuration>
                            <jvmArguments>-Dvaadin.productionMode</jvmArguments>
                        </configuration>
                    </plugin>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
                        <artifactId>vaadin-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>${vaadin.version}</version>
                        <executions>
                            <execution>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>build-frontend</goal>
                                </goals>
                                <phase>compile</phase>
                            </execution>
                        </executions>
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>
            </build>
        </profile>

        <profile>
            <id>it</id>
            <build>
                <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                        <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                        <executions>
                            <execution>
                                <id>start-spring-boot</id>
                                <phase>pre-integration-test</phase>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>start</goal>
                                </goals>
                            </execution>
                            <execution>
                                <id>stop-spring-boot</id>
                                <phase>post-integration-test</phase>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>stop</goal>
                                </goals>
                            </execution>
                        </executions>
                    </plugin>

                    <!-- Runs the integration tests (*IT) after the server is started -->
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                        <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
                        <executions>
                            <execution>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>integration-test</goal>
                                    <goal>verify</goal>
                                </goals>
                            </execution>
                        </executions>
                        <configuration>
                            <trimStackTrace>false</trimStackTrace>
                            <enableAssertions>true</enableAssertions>
                        </configuration>
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>
            </build>
        </profile>

    </profiles>
</project>
```

Comment: Shot in the dark: you are requiring com.vaadin:vaadin, which most likely
pulls in all(?) of the pro components.  Try to use
com.vaadin:vaadin-core instead.

Comment: where do you mean should i use it?

Comment: In your dependencies (the block with all the webjar exclusions)

Comment: thank you but i already have it like

 <exclusion>
        <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
        <artifactId>vaadin-core</artifactId>
  </exclusion>

Comment: `vaadin` (not core) is `vaadin-core` + pro-components (like the board).
Granted, this is not what you're asking, but pulling in those deps does
not help either.  Removing the deps prevents you from accidentally using
them.

Comment: Ahhhh i am so stupid :D I made a comment myself omg.  <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
            <!-- Replace artifactId with vaadin-core to use only free components -->
            <artifactId>vaadin</artifactId>
            <exclusions>

to vaadin-core did the trick

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**TL;DR**

The artifact for `com.vaadin:vaadin` has all the pro-components
referenced and pulls them in.  The artifact you want to use is
`com.vaadin:vaadin-core` -- this only references free components.

---

Over the years there where different ways the license was supposed to be
configured and there are different licenses/levels too; [there is
a whole page dedicated to
it](https://vaadin.com/licensing-faq-and-troubleshooting).

This answer explicitly does not try to answer your explicit problem,
where to find your license key for your version and your level (it's
most likely in `.vaadin` in your home-directory), but suggests to not
include the "pro" components from your build to prevent license problems
at all.